# Selecting range of records with MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query:

```
SELECT  @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number,
    myTable.id
FROM    myTable
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
```

This gives me result with `all` the records in `myTable`. Ex.

```
row_number    id
---------- -------
    1         100
    2         101
    3         102
    4         103
    5         104
    6         105
    7         105
    8         106
    9         107
   10         108
   11         109
   12         110
   13         111
   ...
```

What if I need to select only rows between `6 to 10`? Selecting `1 to 5` is easy with `LIMIT 5`, but how about selecting range of rows in between?

Comment: `LIMIT` also supports an offset. _With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):_ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number,
    myTable.id
FROM myTable  LIMIT 5 OFFSET 6;
```

Use the **OFFSET** with the limit.

LIMIT decide that how much rows will come after query execute and offset decide that from which records the records will be filter.

[Read this tutorial for offset](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.0/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/limit-clause/).

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT  @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number, myTable.id
   FROM myTable LIMIT 6, 5;
```

This will show records 6, 7, 8, 9, 10

Then you get output like

```
row_number    id
---------- -------
    6         105
    7         105
    8         106
    9         107
   10         108
```